# Configure IP adress in Apache in debian machine

Tags: apache, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to setup a new site using apache in debian

BUt when I'm acessing the public domain (e.g. http://31.128.74.178:81/) I get nothing in the browser
The site contains a wordpress blog

This is the website .conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
     ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
      DocumentRoot /var/www/apoint/wordpress
     ServerName domain.com
     <Directory /var/www/apoint/wordpress>
          Options FollowSymlinks
          AllowOverride All
          Require all granted
     </Directory>
     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain.com_error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain.com_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This is the Google cloud 81 port configuration

[image]

How can i fix this?

Comment: Do you have a listener enabled for port 81 in /etc/apache2/ports.conf?

Comment: Within the Linux machine, if you run `netstat -an` do you see anything listening on port 81?  Is it listening on 0.0.0.0 address and not just 127.0.0.1?  Also, when you say you get "nothing in the browser" ... does this mean an empty page or a failure to connect to the Web server?

Answer (score 1):

A few scenarios you can be running into:

1. You don't have the proper firewall rule to allow inbound connections in port 81. If you have UFW (Uncomplicated Firewall) installed in your server, the easiest way to check this is with the command below:

```
sudo ufw status numbered
```

You should get an output like this one:

```
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] OpenSSH                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 2] 81/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 3] OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[ 4] 81/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

If you don't see port 81 listed, then you need to allow it with the following command:

```
sudo ufw allow 81/tcp
```

In case you don't have UFW installed, here you can find a guide on how to install and enable it. Please be very cautious when enabling it, since you could lose access to the server [1].

2. As pointed out by John Hanley, you don't have a listener configured in the /etc/apache2/ports.conf file; in that case, you just need to add the following line in the mentioned file:

```
Listen 81
```

[1] https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-setup-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-debian-10/